# Simple example of a group

Tags: group-theory

I am studying basics of crypto and there is the concept of a group. I tried to set a group like this:

A clock-like object (just a mod 12 thing) will form a group. So say group is g= {0,...,11} and the operation is multiplication i.e *.

* isn't really possible for a group?

- As it has no inverse for 0 and
- for other elements it may not exist afaik.

For example 6 has no inverse, right?

+ Instead seems to form a group?

- For + the inverse for 0 is 1 and the inverse always changes, so for 7 it is 5.
- For + the neutral element is 0

Is this idea correct?

Comment: Your ideas are right, but the inverse of $7$ is $5$.

Comment: fixed thanks @jjagmath

Comment: Why does $0$ have no inverse? If $0+0=0$ then what is $0-0$?

Comment: thanks I literally have no but one book and i thought i could be far off. @jjagmath

Comment: The nice thing about integers modulo a fixed number such as 12 is that it forms a [commutative ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_ring).

Comment: The group is often denoted by $\Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z$, or by $C_{12}$, where the "C" stands for cyclic. It is worth to read the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group).

Comment: https://plus.maths.org/content/maths-a-minute-groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,  the numbers 0-11 mod 12 under addition form a group, as you have the requirements:  It is closed under the operation, the operation is associative, there is an identity element, and everything has an inverse.

Multiplication, as you have noticed,  fails the everything has an inverse part.  It is a weaker form of structure known as a monoid (All groups are monoids, but not visa versa), as a monoid just drops that one group axiom.

note that by removing 0 from your list, multiplication mod 12 still has no inverses for any element that is not coprime to 12, so once again doesn't work. We will sometimes talk about the group that is formed by invertible elements under multiplication,  which are all the elements co-prime to 12.   Those form a group under multiplication

Comment: thank you, it helped. i can not upvote without more than 15 score apparently.

Comment: No worries, accepting the answer is sufficient :).